# Postgres: Is Using Both Prepared Statements and Character Escaping Sufficient to Avoid Malicious User Input Attacks?

Tags: python, postgresql, prepared-statement, sql-injection, database-security

I assume if I use prepared statements and then escape all `'` characters, no input any user dished up could cause me any trouble. But I know there are lots of tricky hacks out there and my assumptions of my database's impenetrableness are often fallible. This question assumes I as the developer am not using any fancy riff-raff, like [PostgreSQL string constants with C-style escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE), for example.

As a sample of my 'foolproof' input sanitization, I have the following script (this question is language-agnostic for the scripting code, but for reference, the snippet is in Python using the `psycopg2` library):

```py
user_input = function_that_returns_user_input_string()

#replace any single quotes with two single quotes
modified_input = user_input.replace("'", "''")

cursor.execute(
    "PREPARE mystatement AS "
    "SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable WHERE mycolumn=$1;"
)
cursor.execute(
    f"EXECUTE mystatement ('{modified_input}');"
)

res = cursor.fetchall()
function_that_handles_data_and_does_etc()
```

Is there anything `function_that_returns_user_input_string()` could return to do SQL injection or any other hack? And if so, what?

In addition, let's go with a scenario where my script has a simple `INSERT` statement instead of a `SELECT` one, if that makes any difference in the answer to my question.

Comment: With a prepared statement you don't need to escape single quotes at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Even the weird way he is doing it?